# How to understand jstack output

Tags: jstack

Does this mean that I have a dead lock?
Do anyone has some ideas on this?

```
"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f8a30bef800 nid=0x6318 in Object.wait()        [0x00007f8a0dfa9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x0000000741501260> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:189)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f8a30bed800 nid=0x6317 in Object.wait() [0x00007f8a0e0aa000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000007415012f8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
```